# Computing all distinct pair-combinations from N elements

Tags: combinations

Working on a [USACO programming problem](http://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=pKMCOAuehM7&S=wormhole), I got stuck when using a brute-force approach.

From a list of N elements, I need to compute all distinct pair-configurations.

My problem is twofold.

1. How do I express such a configuration in, lets say, an array?
2. How do I go about computing all distinct combinations?

I only resorted to the brute-force approach after I gave up solving it analytically. Although this is context-specific, I came as far as noting that one can quickly rule out the rows where there is only a single, so called, "wormhole" --- it isn't effectively in an infinite cycle.

**Update**

I'll express them with a tree structure. Set N = 6; {A,B,C,D,E,F}.
By constructing the following trees chronologically, all combinations are listed.

A --> B,C,D,E,F;

B --> C,D,E,F;

C --> D,E,F;

D --> E,F;

E --> F.

Check: in total there are 6 over 2 = 6!/(2!*4!) = 15 combinations.

**Note.** Once a lower node is selected, it should be discarded as a top node; it can only exist in one single pair.

Next, selecting them and looping over all configurations.

Comment: Do you need some hint, or just the solution?

Comment: @WhatsUp Never the solution, that's my job. A subtle conceptual hint would be nice.

Comment: In view of the constraint of this problem (i.e. `N <= 12`), there are at most `11 * 9 * 7 * 5 * 3 * 1 = 10395` possible pair-combinations. You can simply go through every possibility, and judge if it contains a loop.

Comment: You can express a configuration by an array `c[N]`, in the way that the `i`-th wormhole is linked to the `c[i]`-th wormhole. Then use a recursive function to loop over all configurations.

Comment: @WhatsUp Can you give me a hint on how to write the recursive function? I think that you mean that I should use backtracking on the tree structure I mentioned before.

Comment: See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code (in C/C++):

```
int c[N];
void LoopOverAll(int n)
{
    if (n == N)
    {
        // output, the array c now contains a configuration
        // do anything you want here
        return;
    }
    if (c[n] != - 1)
    {
        // this warmhole is already paired with someone
        LoopOverAll(n + 1);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = n + 1; i < N; i ++)
    {
        if (c[i] != - 1)
        {
            // this warmhole is already paired with someone
            continue;
        }
        c[i] = n; c[n] = i; LoopOverAll(n + 1);
        c[i] = - 1;
    }
    c[n] = - 1;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        c[i] = - 1;

    LoopOverAll(0);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this function, it seems very concise (I'm not yet used to recursive functions).

Comment: It seems to only compute five configurations with N = 12.

Comment: Furthermore only the first configuration if computes is correct:
(((0:1 1:0 2:3 3:2 4:5 5:4 6:7 7:6 8:9 9:8 10:11 11:10))) |||
 
(((0:1 1:0 2:3 3:2 4:5 5:4 6:9 7:11 8:11 9:6 10:11 11:7))) |||

(((0:1 1:0 2:3 3:2 4:9 5:11 6:11 7:11 8:11 9:4 10:11 11:5))) |||

(((0:1 1:0 2:9 3:11 4:11 5:11 6:11 7:11 8:11 9:2 10:11 11:3))) ||| 

(((0:9 1:11 2:11 3:11 4:11 5:11 6:11 7:11 8:11 9:0 10:11 11:1)))

Comment: @MusséRedi Sorry, I forgot one line in the codes. Now fixed: just add `c[n] = - 1;` to the end of the function `LoopOverAll`.

Comment: @MusséRedi You can try to trace the function step by step with small `N` (e.g. `N = 4` or `6`), which might help you understand better how it works.